# HandleBars - How to Iterate 2 Collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I know how to iterate a single collection, but how do I iterate multiple collections using Handlebars?

Below is my routing file

```
EmployeePayslip.find({"employeeName":""+name}, function(err, db_payslip){
if(err) throw err;
SalaryItems.find({"employeeName":""+name}, function(err,db_salaryItems){
  if(err) throw err;
  res.render('AdminView/pages/examples/payslip-details',{
    payslip:db_payslip,
    salaryItem:db_salaryItems
   });
  });
 });
});
```

How do I do something like below,

```
{{each payslip}}
  <label>{{employeeName}}</label>

  {{each salaryItem}}
    <label>{{item}}</label>
  {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

If I only use one *each*, the iteration works, but if I nested it, it does not seem to display the data. How do I display the data from both collection?

Comment: Do you want to duplicate the Salary Item data for each Pay Slip? Would it not be as simple as `../salaryItem`?

Comment: @76484 hey thanks for thr reply! Im sorry if my question is a bit unclear, what i want to achieve is to display data from 2 different collections with handlebars. How can I do that with your suggestion above?

Comment: Like @76484 says: replace `each salaryItem` with `each ../salaryItem` in your template.

Comment: @robertklep @76484Thank you so much it worked. If i have another each inside `each ../salaryItem` would it be like `each ../../bonuses`?

Comment: Yes. Give it a try!